# Union and QT-Formfileds

Tags: qt

calculator.h

```
#ifndef CALCULATORFORM_H
#define CALCULATORFORM_H

#include "ui_calculatorform.h"

class CalculatorForm : public QWidget, private Ui::CalculatorForm
{
Q_OBJECT

  public:
  CalculatorForm(QWidget *parent = 0);

private slots:
  void on_inputSpinBox1_valueChanged(unsigned short value);
  void on_inputSpinBox2_valueChanged(unsigned short value);
};

#endif
```

My program:

```
class my
{
public:
  union urgl
  {
    unsigned short   a[2];
    float       f;
  };
  urgl obj;
};

void CalculatorForm::on_inputSpinBox1_valueChanged(unsigned short value) {
  my v;
  v.obj.a[0]=inputSpinBox1->value;
  v.obj.a[1]=inputSpinBo2->value;
  outputWidget->setText(QString::number( inputSpinBox2->v.obj.f()));
}

void CalculatorForm::on_inputSpinBox2_valueChanged(unsigned short value)
{
  my v;
  v.obj.a[0]=inputSpinBox1->value;
  v.obj.a[1]=inputSpinBox2->value; 
  outputWidget->setText(QString::number( inputSpinBox1->v.obj.f()));
}
```

I'm getting some errors:

```
'QSpinBox::value' from type 'int (QSpinBox::)() const' to type 'short                 unsigned int'
 v.obj.a[0]=inputSpinBox1->value;
           ^
 ..\multipleinheritance\calculatorform.cpp:74:16: error: 'inputSpinBo2' was not declared in this scope
 v.obj.a[1]=inputSpinBo2->value;
            ^
 **strong text**..\multipleinheritance\calculatorform.cpp:75:59: error: 'class QSpinBox' has no member named 'v'
 outputWidget->setText(QString::number( inputSpinBox2->v.obj.f()));
                                                       ^
 ..\multipleinheritance\calculatorform.cpp: At global scope:
 ..\multipleinheritance\calculatorform.cpp:71:67: warning: unused parameter      'value' [-Wunused-parameter]
  void CalculatorForm::on_inputSpinBox1_valueChanged(unsigned short value)
                                                               ^
..\multipleinheritance\calculatorform.cpp: In member function 'void      CalculatorForm::on_inputSpinBox2_valueChanged(short unsigned int)':
..\multipleinheritance\calculatorform.cpp:83:15: error: cannot convert 'QSpinBox::value' from type 'int (QSpinBox::)() const' to type 'short unsigned      int'
 v.obj.a[0]=inputSpinBox1->value;
           ^
 ..\multipleinheritance\calculatorform.cpp:84:15: error: cannot convert 'QSpinBox::value' from type 'int (QSpinBox::)() const' to type 'short unsigned int'
 v.obj.a[1]=inputSpinBox2->value;
           ^
 ..\multipleinheritance\calculatorform.cpp:86:59: error: 'class QSpinBox' has no member named 'v'
 outputWidget->setText(QString::number( inputSpinBox1->v.obj.f()));
                                                       ^
 ..\multipleinheritance\calculatorform.cpp: At global scope:
 ..\multipleinheritance\calculatorform.cpp:80:67: warning: unused parameter 'value' [-Wunused-parametervoid 

CalculatorForm::on_inputSpinBox2_valueChanged(unsigned short value)
                                                                   ^
Makefile.Debug:592: recipe for target 'debug/calculatorform.o' failed
```

Where can I call "my" class so it can be accessed by the other classes?
How can I show the float value in a output textfield?
I'm using Qt Designer 5.5

Comment: Sorry, typos are off-topic here. Read the code carefully, and make sure that there are no typos. So far, all I see is typos, typos, typos. Understand what the code means.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues that can be all bundled as "typos".

`QSpinBox::value` is a function, so you should be calling it:

```
v.obj.a[0]=inputSpinBox1->value(); // correct
v.obj.a[0]=inputSpinBox1->value; // wrong
```

`my::urgl.f` is not callable, so you should *not* be calling it, and the spinboxes don't have a `v` member either:

```
outputWidget->setText(QString::number(v.obj.f)); // correct
outputWidget->setText(QString::number(inputSpinBox2->v.obj.f())); // wrong
```

Your slot types are wrong:

```
void on_inputSpinBox1_valueChanged(int value); // correct
void on_inputSpinBox1_valueChanged(unsigned short value); // wrong
```

> Where can I call "my" class [...]

That class is not callable - it does not implement `operator()()`.  Calling a class instance is not synonymous with accessing it. Use the word "call" only when you literally mean calling a callable object.

> [...] so it can be accessed by the other classes?

What other classes want to access it? Show the code. So far, nowhere in your code is there "another class" that would "access" an instance of `my`.

> How can I show the float value in a output textfield?

Like you do, although I have no idea why do you try to manually merge two short ints into a float... If this is some demo of a float's binary structure, then sure this works, but I doubt that it's what you meant. At a minimum, you'd want the integer types to have definite size: `uint16_t` or `quint16`, `short int` is not guaranteed to be 16 bits wide.

You do know that you can use a `QDoubleSpinBox` to get floating point values directly, right?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My case:
I get two 16bit integer values from an energy meter over modbus-tcp.
This two values i have to interprate as a 32 Bit Float.
Like this:
1. 16Bit value.........|2. 16Bit value.........|

1010111101110101|1110000111101110|

+                                                            +
+------------------32 Bit Float---------------+

Comment: No I've got it like this:
http://pastebin.com/dDYftr9s
The issue is, it seems the second input field seems to be ignored. Output box only changes the value when i change input box one.

Comment: @knuppel If you wish to add details, please edit your question. Do not use pastebin for code snippets, include them directly in the text of the question.

Comment: @knuppel This answer tells you what to fix. Have you implemented the fixes? Does it work?